# Redis cluster setup on windows

Tags: redis

while running reds cluster setup on windows server 2012,i am getting error- slot 0 is already in use.Someone could please help me.i am using ruby script to run cluter-tribe.rb file.

Comment: Try a [CLUSTER RESET](http://redis.io/commands/cluster-reset) first